# android cannot resolve symbol R

Tags: android

when i add or update a dependency in app gradle class R will not find in my activity class.

```
 "android cannot resolve symbol R"
```

[image]

Comment: click on "sync now"

Comment: I did it, but it dose not work!

Comment: That means you have some errors while building the project. Find and fix them

Comment: provide your logcat report, an error is something else

Comment: Terminal -> `gradlew clean build`. That'll show any errors in your build process.

Comment: Check your package name that file, sometime it occurs due to package mismatch.    If package is ok, then re-starting a project may help.

Comment: check res folder

Answer (score 2):

Top yellow bar has a function "Sync now". You can click it and it will sync the Gradle files.

If this doesn't work you can try

> Build > Clean Project
>
> Build > Rebuild Project

You can also try

> File > Sync Project with Gradle Files

Comment: In a case like this question please close the question against the canonical duplicate.